# jQuery: "this" can't find element generated by .html()

Tags: jquery, this

First of all, sorry if the subject is not clear.

I'm trying to build a simple sequenced menu. The user click on the first option and then he find new suboptions. I think the code speaks for itself.

```
<div id="box">
Welcome text<br>
<ul>
    <li class="option" id="opt1">Option 1</li>
    <li class="option" id="opt2">Option 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var nextText = "<p>Next text with two more options.</p><ul><li class='option' id='opt1a'>Option 1a</li><li class='option' id='opt1b'>Option 1b</li></ul>";

$("#box li").click(function() {
  var ev = $(this).attr('id');
  if (ev==="opt1") {
    $("#box").html(nextText);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should render the entire menu in the html, and hide / show it accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the click handler to the elements that existed when the page was first loaded. Elements that are added later don't have the click bindings. You can solve this in jQuery using delegation with `.on`:

```
$("#box").on("click", "li", function() {
    var ev = $(this).attr('id');
    if (ev = "opt1") {
        $("#box").html(nextText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar. I tried your example and it worked for me. :-)